# Why is this managed array initialization wrong?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, c++-cli

I want to declare a managed array because I need to do a search on a ListView but this declaration is wrong and I get these errors:

```
array<ListViewItem^, 128> searchedItems = gcnew array<ListViewItem^>;

E0070   incomplete type is not allowed
E0079   expected a type specifier
```

I need it to work from here, which is a button click event from the Main Form:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click_1(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    String^ searchString = tbDenominazione->Text;
    array<ListViewItem^>^ itemsSearched = gcnew array<ListViewItem^>^(listViewMain->Items->Count);
    int i = 0;
    int matches = 0;
    for (; i < listViewMain->Items->Count; i++) {
        ListViewItem^ currentItem = listViewMain->Items[i];
//      String^ currentItemText = currentItem->Text;

//      cout << msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(currentItem->SubItems[1]->ToString());      
        
        if (currentItem->SubItems[1]->Text->Contains(searchString)) {
            matches++;
        } 
    }
    cout << "Corrispondenze trovate: " << matches << endl;
}
```

Comment: Try: `array<ListViewItem^> ^ searchedItems = gcnew array<ListViewItem^>(128);`.

Comment: @wohlstad the right part is still expecting a type specifier, the declaration is done inside the body of a click event

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: The snippet does not reproduce error E0070.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT What type of C++ language standard are you using? Because I am using C++17.

Comment: @wohlstad I posted the snippet of code where it should run

Comment: @wohlstad should I include something in my project? I don't understand why I can't make arrays

Comment: Now you have an extra '^' after the `gcnew`. It should be `array<ListViewItem^>^ itemsSearched = gcnew array<ListViewItem^>(listViewMain->Items->Count);`.

Comment: @wohlstad It is saying that I have `E0442 too few arguments for class template "std::array"` for the left operand and `E0079   expected a type specifier` for the right operand.

Comment: `std::array` is c++. This is a c++/cli (i.e. .NET) array which is different. Do you have `#include <array>` anywhere together with `using namespace std;` ? If so you should remove it (it's for the c++ `std::array`). And `using namespace std;` is bad practice anyway.

Answer (score -3):

I solved specifying this

```
cli::array<ListViewItem^, 128> searchedItems = gcnew cli::array<ListViewItem^>;
```

Comment: I really don't believe you.  The left-hand side is a 128-dimensional array handle.  In C# that would be written `ListViewItem[,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,]` except there would be even more commas.  It cannot store a handle to a single-dimensional array object.